# context state update not reflected in another nexjs page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

Why is the state not updating when `setFocus` is called?

focus-context.js:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const FocusContext = createContext()
const FocusUpdateContext = createContext()

export function useFocus() {
  return useContext(FocusContext)
}

export function useFocusUpdate() {
  return useContext(FocusUpdateContext)
}

export function FocusProvider({ children }) {
  let [focus, setFocus] = useState({
    todo: false,
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('TESTE', focus)
  }, [focus])

  function updateFocus(t) {
    console.log('Q', t)
    setFocus({ todo: 'BUNGA' })
  }

  return (
    <FocusUpdateContext.Provider value={updateFocus}>
      <FocusContext.Provider value={focus}>{children}</FocusContext.Provider>
    </FocusUpdateContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

TimerApplet.js (other page):

```
import { useFocus } from '../../../store/focus-context'

export default function TimerApplet() {
  const focus = useFocus().focus

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='app'>{`current task: ${focus.todo}`}</div>
      content
      <style jsx>{`
        .container {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100vh;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          margin: 0 !important;
        }
        .app {
          height: 30rem;
          width: 30rem;
          background-color: wheat;
        }
      `}</style>
    </div>
  )
}
```

nextjs root component:

```
import { FocusProvider } from '../store/focus-context'
import '../styles/globals.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <FocusProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </FocusProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: Copied your code into a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/why-is-the-state-not-updating-in-react-context-edit-im-on-nextjs-btw-6xc04) and it seems to update without issue. What is the issue you are seeing? Can you provide more detail? How are you consuming the context values?

Comment: i guess its not reflected in ui. I need to access `focus` in multiple pages in nextjs. I have the combined provider in `_app.js`

Comment: I could create several more "children" components, all accessing the context value, and I'm certain they all would update. Can you share how you're using the context values? How you are accessing them? Are you sure your `FocusProvider` is wrapping all the React-subtrees that need/want to access it?

Comment: Ok, I see. So `TimerApplet` is a component rendered by `MyApp` somewhere? Think you could create a nextjs codesandbox demo we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: I think I fixed it. The problem was duplicate providers. Thank you anyways @DrewReese

Answer (score 0):

The problem was duplicate providers. Fixed.